# Splitting a period-delimited string into multiple strings

Tags: java, android

I have a string

```
String x = "Hello.August 27th.Links.page 1";
```

I am wondering if I can split this string into 4 other strings based on where the period is. For example, the four other strings would be,

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "August 27th";
String c = "Links";
String d = "page 1";
```

As you can see I basically want to extract certain parts of the string out into a new string, the place where it is extracted is based on where the period is which ends the first string and then shows where the 2nd and, etc. strings end.

Thanks in advance!

In android btw

Comment: I would've said this showed lack of research, except for the regex gotcha

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (note that it receives a regex as a parameter)

```
String x = "Hello.August 27th.Links.page 1";
String[] splitted = x.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course just use:

```
  String[] stringParts =  myString.split("\\.")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String x = "Hello.August 27th.Links.page 1"
String []ar=x.split("[.]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use StringTokenizer for this requirement. Here is the simple approach:

```
String x = "Hello.August 27th.Links.page 1";
        if (x.contains(".")) {
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(x, ".");
            String[] arrayOfString = new String[stringTokenizer.countTokens()];
            int i = 0;
            while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                arrayOfString[i] = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(arrayOfString[0]);
            System.out.println(arrayOfString[1]);
            System.out.println(arrayOfString[2]);
            System.out.println(arrayOfString[3]);
        }
```

You are done. :)